# UIPageViewController does not allow UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to be recognized

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have this problem with my app. As you can see on the storyboard screen below there is root VC (`ContainerViewController`) which has a `UIScrollView` and inside this scrollview there are two containers. In the left container there is `MenuViewController` embedded and in the right container there is `WelcomeViewController` embedded. `WelcomeViewController` has an `UIPageViewController` inside.

[image: storyboard screenshot]

The idea is to have a slide-out menu on the left (using scrollView) and multiple VCs on the right inside the `UIPageViewController`. I have implemented `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to show the menu from the left edge. It works correctly with the scrollView with this code:

```
edgePanRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftScreenEdgeSwiped))
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(edgePanRecognizer)
```

However on the area where UIPageViewController is located, UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer is not recognized and instead of sliding out menu I can only swipe between pages.
I have tried with

```
func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer,shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
         return true
}
```

but it does not work.

I would appreciate any help how to make `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to have priority over `UIPageViewController` gestures.

Comment: Any success on this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` work with `UIPageViewController`, you must add the gesture recognizer to the `view` property of the page view controller instance.

Example:

```
let edgePanRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(edgeAction(_:)))
edgePanRecognizer.edges = .left        
pageViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(edgePanRecognizer)
```

In addition to this, it's essential to add this line of code:

```
(pageViewController.view.subviews.filter { $0 is UIScrollView }.first as? UIScrollView)?.panGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: edgePanRecognizer)
```